# How to select distinct based on combination of two fields with LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework-5, where-clause

How can I select only the records that have a distinct combination of only two values in a row?

For instance, say I have the following:

```
Name     |     Age     |     Height
------------------------------------
Joe          19               99
Kim          19               76
Joe          20               88
Joe          19               69
```

How could I write a LINQ expression to select only the rows with the same `Name` AND `Age`?

I tried:
`var count = context.people.Where(p => (p.age && p.name).Distinct());`
and `var count = context.people.Where(p => (p.age.Distinct() && p.name.Distinct()));`

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: What exactly does the output you're expecting looks like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select just the name and age into an anonymous type, and then use `Distinct()`:

```
var results = context.people
                     .Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Age })
                     .Distinct();
```

Obviously that won't give you the height, but then there *is* no single height. If you want all the heights as well, you need to group instead:

```
var results = context.people
                     .GroupBy(p => new { p.Name, p.Age });
```

That will give you a sequence of groupings, where each grouping contains all the people with the same name and age.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GroupBy` for these scenarios in linq:

```
var result = people.GroupBy(p => new{p.Name, p.Age})
```

<del>.Select(g => g.Key)</del>

Update:
As Jon Skeet mentioned, this gives you a list of grouping based on `Name` and `Age` values. Then you can for example add `.Select(g => g.Max(p => p.Height))` to get the result of type `List<Person>` which contains the top tallest ones in every Name/Age group.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to use GroupBy here, if only the name and age are required.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You're right. but since op mentioned selecting `rows` I assumed he meant to include Height as well.

Comment: But in that case your solution also fails, because it's only selecting the Key (which is the name and age)

Answer (score 0):

For new .NET versions, you can use `DistinctBy`:

```
var results = context.people
                     .DistinctBy(p => new { p.Name, p.Age });
```